# Errors in setting up AcrobatMenu

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I am testing Adobe Acrobat Menu. At the bottom of the page, it should have 
"Previous Next First Last Back Forward"

Here's my MWE. Can you point out why my code is not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[colorlinks{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\NavigationalBar}{%
 \Acrobatmenu{PrevPage}{Previous}
 \Acrobatmenu{NextPage}{Next}
 \Acrobatmenu{FirstPage}{First}
 \Acrobatmenu{LastPage}{Last}
 \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{Back}
 \Acrobatmenu{GoForward}{Forward}
}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \NavigationalBar
  \section{Document start}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \NavigationalBar
  \section{Last section}
  \lipsum[4]
  \NavigationalBar
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might help to replace `\usepackage[colorlinks{hyperref}` with `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`. Incidentally, how or where is `\NavigationalBar` defined?

Comment: @Mico - thank you for the advice. I figure it out. I was blind.